# High CPU usage of PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, cpu-usage

I have a PostgreSQL backed complex Ruby on Rails application running on a Ubuntu Virtual Machine. I see the Postgres processes are having **very high** **%CPU** values while running "top"commands.

. Periodically the **%CPU** is going up to **94** and **95**.

```
lscpu
```

gives the fallowing output

```
   Architecture:          i686
   CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
   Byte Order:            Little Endian
   CPU(s):                4
   On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
   Thread(s) per core:    1
   Core(s) per socket:    1
   Socket(s):             4
   Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
   CPU family:            6
   Model:                 85
   Stepping:              4
   CPU MHz:               2100.000
   BogoMIPS:              4200.00
   L1d cache:             32K
   L1i cache:             32K
   L2 cache:              1024K
   L3 cache:              33792K
```

> top -n1
> [image: top -n1]
>
> top -c
> [image: top -c]

I want the know the reason for the High CPU utilization by Postgres.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Check que query ran by pid with:
psql -c "select * from pg_stat_activity where pid = xxx;"

Comment: You have to find the statements that cause the load. Use `pg_stat_statements`.

Comment: I have seen high CPU load on databases that didn't have usable indexes to satisfy the queries that were executed. Check pg_stat_user_tables and pg_stat_user_indexes to see if your indexes are used and what tables don't have indexes that are used. And sometimes an index won't add any value, that also happens.